# Android studio permission denied error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been using the new android studio happily since launch, but today I tried to build a project and got the following:

```
android-apt-compiler: [app_name] C:\Users\andrew\projects\app_name\res\values\strings.xml___jb_old___: error: Unable to open file for read: Permission denied
```

I have a file called strings.xml, but nothing called that name. I've tried to delete the file and pull it back in from SVN and I've also tried the local history option to go back in time and rollback to before the issue happened, but I now can't get any further with this. I've tried a project clean and build but to no avail. That's with the latest version (the version built on June 6th)

Comment: I managed to get around it by trying to delete the whole directory. It failed due to not being able to delete strings.xml___jb_old___ so I then rebooted and the file had gone and things work again

Comment: You might as well list your workaround as an answer and accept it (just in case others have a similar issue). Once you accept your answer as the solution, this question will get better positioning in google search results versus a question that has had no answer whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around it by trying to delete the whole directory. It failed due to not being able to delete strings.xml_**jb_old_** so I then rebooted and the file had gone and things work again